# ZF2 & Apigility - Correct way to setup GET and POST RPC services

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

What is the correct way to setup GET and POST services in ApiGility?

**Currently, if I am setting up a GET service, I will include the variable I require in my route:**

> /api/verify/merchant[/:merchant_code]

**And if I wish to setup a POST service, my route becomes:**

> /api/verify/merchant
>
> And I add a **merchant_code** 'field'

**And if I want my route to accept both POST and GET, I then do this:**

> /api/verify/merchant[/:merchant_code]
>
> and add a merchant_code field as well...

Is this the correct way to setup the routing for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you `POST` your new entities on the collection endpoint so in your case `/api/verify/merchant`. The server will respond with a new resource with a self href for the newly created `Merchant`. This href will be formatted like `/api/verify/merchant[/merchant_code]` where `merchant_code` will be the identifier for the newly added `Merchant` resource.

Sending a `POST` request to `/api/verify/merchant[/merchant_code]` is not necessary/valid. You do `GET`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` or `PUT` requests on the endpoint of your Merchant resource depending on the action you want to perform (read, update, delete, replace).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation this helps a lot. Not sure why anyone would down vote the question though.